# Getting: Error Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\users' not found

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

First of all I want to say that I tried similar problems with solutions which I found on Stack Overflow.

I just migrated fresh and the problem started... Tried `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` and `npm update vue-loader` did not help.
It seems that something is wrong with users model, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

users model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\users as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class users extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'username',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\users;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\users
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return users::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `composer.lock` file and again fire `composer update`. If it does not work then try to fire `composer update --no-scripts`.

Comment: Did not helped. Tried both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\users as Authenticatable` to `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable` in the `User` model.

Because there is no `users` class in `Auth`.

Let me know its solves your issue or not.